# Error trying to instantiate class, within a other class

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to access a class "Skills" and using the class within a other class "Employee" to add skills within the employee. but I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: Skill is not defined at Employee.js:21, and can't figure out why

```
 class Skill{
    constructor(sId){
        this.sId = sId;
    }
}
if (localStorage.getItem("Skill") == null) {
    var skillList =[];
    skillList.push(new Skill("Rekruttering"));
    skillList.push(new Skill("Bogføring"));
    skillList.push(new Skill("Engros-salg"));
    skillList.push(new Skill("JavaScript"));

  if(localStorage.getItem("Skill") == null){
      skillListString = JSON.stringify(skillList);
      localStorage.setItem("Skill", skillListString);
  }
else {
    skillList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Skill"));
  }

class Employee {
    // vi bruger en constructor funktion for at lave en opskrift på objekter af en bestemt type.
    //this metoden benyttes til at referere til det tilhørende objekt
    constructor(name, gender, department, yy, email, skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.skills = [];
    }
    addNewSkill(skill){
        this.skills.push(skill);
    }
}


//Employee Database "Localstorage"
if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
    let employeeList = [];
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "2650@mail.dk",new Skill("Sales")));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "1234@email.com"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", "Female", "Sales",1998, "Mail2@mail.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", "Male","IT", 1997, "blabla@mail.dk"));

    if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
        employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList);
        localStorage.setItem("Employee", employeeListString);
        employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
    }
} else {
    employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
    document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
}
```

Comment: Are both the classes defined in the same file?

Comment: Nope, could that be the reason?

Comment: @PaulMcLoughlin

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the file that contains the Skills class to where it is being used.

So you would need to export the `Skill` class first, from the file where it has been declared.

- Using ES5: `module.exports = Skill` at the bottom of the file.
- Using
  ES6: `export default Skill;`

then you would import at the top of your file where Skill is being used.

- Using ES5 `const Skill = require('Location of file containing skill class goes here')`
- Using ES6 `import Skill from 'location of file containing skill class'`

For more information: https://javascript.info/import-export

Comment: And how is that done?! I thought my texteditor was "smart" enough to do that. Im just using Vanilla JS

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I saw the edit. I just get a syntax error.. Should that be ignored?

Comment: export default Skill; and I get the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen I've updated my answer, follow the ES5 examples.

Comment: @BenjaminNielsen any luck with my answer?

Comment: unfortunately :( Thx for taking your time though